# Python unitest mock to check that a method returns a method call

Tags: python, mocking

I'm trying to figure out how I can simply check that the execute_db returns
a method call with the name cursor.fetchone?

I'm not interested to see if the db works, that will be done in a integration test later on.

I've written a small unittest already, but here I'm only mocking the return value.. I want to find a way to test that the method with the given name is being called as well.

```
class DataChecker:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize class
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("pos.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def execute_db(self, query, params=None):
        # Execute SQL query with parameters and return data
        self.cursor.execute(query, [params])
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.cursor.fetchone()
```

Test:

```
def test_execute_db():
    mock_datachecker = Mock()
    mock_datachecker.cursor.fetchone.return_value = "one"
    assert DataChecker.execute_db(mock_datachecker, "SELECT * FROM Customers;", 1) == "one"
```

Comment: Maybe if you assert that self.cursor.fetchone() was called in this function is enough, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

You would mock the method `fetchone` from **sqlite3** that is imported in `DataChecker` module.

**db.py**

```py
import sqlite3


class DataChecker:
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize class
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("pos.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def execute_db(self, query, params=None):
        # Execute SQL query with parameters and return data
        if params:
            self.cursor.execute(query, params)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(query)
        self.conn.commit()
        return self.cursor.fetchone()
```

Then you could use the `db.sqlite3` to mock the `connect().cursor().fetchone` method.

```py
def test_execute_db():
    with patch('db.sqlite3') as mock_db:
        mock_db.connect().cursor().fetchone.return_value = "one"

        assert DataChecker().execute_db("SELECT * FROM Customers") == "one"
```